# jQuery animation loop with images

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-animate

I want to create a really simple slideshow using opacity animation. I can't use fadeIn or fadeOut functions because setting display:none will crash my layout.

I have these 4 fixed images, and what I want to do is to animate opacity to 0, then change img src, and then animate opacity to 1 again.

Any ideas? How could I make it loop forever?

Thanks.

Comment: Can include `html` , `css` , `js` tried ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try placing `img` elements inside of a parent element container ;
utilizing `.fadeTo()`, which does not adjust `display` property of `css` , at last index element within parent element container ;  when animation complete , adjust `opacity` of `img` to `1` ; call `.prependTo()` to move `img` to first index within parent element container ; repeat infinitely.

```js
(function fx() {
  return $("div img").eq(-1).delay(1500).fadeTo(3000, 0, function() {
    $(this).css("opacity", "1").prependTo($(this).parent())
  }).promise().then(fx);
}).call($("div img"));
```

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
div img {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400/cats" />
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400/technics" />
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400/nature" />
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400/animals" />
</div>
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help, but I can't have images position:absolute nor use fade functions (that uses the display property). That why I wanted to use visibility instead.

Comment: @LeandroFaria See updated post. Substituted `position:fixed` for `position:absolute` ; `.fadeTo` does not adjust `display` property. To confirm this , could open `console` , inspect images during animations; `.fadeTo` utilizes only `opacity` property.

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuerys [animate](https://api.jquery.com/animate/) method. First you use it on the image you want to fade out and set the opacity to 0 and after changing the image source you have to use it to change the opacity to 1.

For the endless loop: You can call a function every X ms with [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval).
So you have to put all your code that changes the image within a function (let's call it `changeImage` for now) and then make use of `setInterval`. You can start it with `setInterval(changeImage, 3000)` and the image will change every 3 seconds for example.